# Get and output JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I know this propably got answered very often but I still don't get it.

The only information I need is "up" and "down".

I got some JSON API Data and just want to get some specific data from it and just output it via `alert()`.

What I got:

```
  $.getJSON('URL', function(data) {
    jsonData = data;
  });
  alert(data['items'][0]['up'][0]);
```

What the JSON looks like:

[image: JSON Data picture]

I tried to do this with the help of the [mozilla wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)...

Comment: Move `alert` inside the callback. Also, `up` is a number, not an array, so you want to omit the `[0]` after `['up']`.